# following one tutorial of spring boot and jsp.getting following error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Error

There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

Controller : ApplicationController

```
@Controller
public class ApplicationController {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String hello()
    {
        return "hello";

    }


    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public String welcome()
    {
        return "welcomepage";

    }

}
```

JSP :  welcomepage.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>welcome to jsp page</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Comment: Don't you need to specify the mapping for the welcome() method? @RequestMapping("/welcome")

Comment: when are you getting this error?